# Checking the existence of an object with a certain property within an array

Tags: javascript, list, search, object

Bear in mind, I don't quite have the vocabulary yet to know what keywords to search for (just jumping on the coding bandwagon now...), so this might be a really easy question to answer!

I have an array of objects, say

```
M = [A_1, A_2, ..., A_n]
```

, where A_i is an instantiation of the class

```
A = {text: "string", coords:[x,y]}
```

My question is: what is the quick, elegant, simple way of checking whether my array M contains an object A_i where

```
A_i.text="your mom" && A_i.coords = [9,9]
```

is true?

I've got access to underscore.js which seems to have some nifty ways of doing things, but I'm a little confused on how to implement it...

Something I've tried (with the underscore.js library) is:

```
var isitso = _.find(M, function (i) { 
    return i.text == "your mom" && i.coords == [9,9];
});
```

At this stage of learning JS, I would appreciate as many different ways of solving this problem.  Just to see what can be done and how.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The specific terms and keywords are not as important as good code formatting. Please read the FAQ on how to use markdown to properly format your questions.

Comment: Thanks, prettied it up a little.

Comment: Does the example you showed not work?

Comment: It does not.  Printing the result to the console comes up with "undefined"

Comment: Just some notes about the terms used in js. "A = {text: "string", coords:[x,y]}" is an instantiation of an *object literal*, not a class. There are no classes in js (yet). Further along those lines, if you were to say that A_i is an instantiation of A, then A would be a function that returns a new instance of the object. See this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/BcpVB/

Comment: Thanks Geuis, that clears up quite a bit about objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficultly with what you have is that array equality is reference equality (they have to be the same memory location), not value equality (they have the same values).  If you change your check to:

```
      return i.text == 'your mom' && i.coords[0] == 9 && i.coords[1] == 9;
```

it should work.  In this case you're check whether the first (0) and second (1) elements have the requisite values not comparing the array objects themselves.  Comparing numbers does compare values rather than references.

Comment: Fantastic.  Is there a way to check value equality of arrays without breaking an array down into its components and then checking scalar equality?

Comment: @psychetician - write a function that iterates over the arrays, checking each value and only returns true if it gets through the entirety of both arrays without finding a difference. A small optimization would be to first check that they are the same length before checking the values.  You can also return false on the first difference, aborting the rest of the comparisons.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `===` instead of `==`?

Comment: @ErikE - in this case it seems readily apparent that the first is a string and the coordinates are integers so no type conversion would be done anyway as they are of the same type.

Comment: Which is exactly why you use `===`. To allow type conversion you use `==`. Not using `===` when you don't want to allow type conversion violates best practice. Your logic is completely backwards.

Comment: @ErikE - what i'm saying is type conversion won't take place and thus doesn't matter.  i'm ok with someone entering the coordinates as strings as I know that they are really numbers and comparing them with type conversion is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can't check arrays for equality. You need to do something like:

```
_.find(M, function (i) { 
    return i.text == "your mom" && i.coords[0] == 9 && i.coords[1] == 9;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use _.filter  method.

```
var filtered = _.filter(M, function(i) { return (i.text == "text2" && i.cords[0] == 3 && i.cords[1] == 4) });
```

Comment: @Xymostech, yes It didn't work because array equality does not work like that. I just wanted to emphasize _.filter function. But now it should work. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BuddhiP/QMLVb/1/

Comment: Why do you want to emphasize the `_.filter` function? Does `_.find` not work well enough?

Comment: @Xymostech, well find returns the first one, and filter returns all that match. Make your pick. :)

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of underscore js, so I cannot speak to its details.  Most javacript frameworks have a foreach method of one type or another, to emulate the not-yet-standardized foreach loop.

```
function findMatches(/* target array*/ target, /* matching function*/ match) {
   var dummy = [];
   dojo.forEach(target, function(t) {
        if (match(t)) {
            dummy.push(t);
        }
   });
   return dummy;
}

var allMatches = findMatches(M, function (m) {
    m.text == "your mom" && m.coords == [9,9]
});
```

Note that `dojo.forEach` is the forEach in the Dojo library I use.  jQuery also contains such a thing of your preferred library does not.

Its late, I haven't put this code in an actual browser, but the idea is sound, even if I made a typo.

Comment: I see some underscore experts have been by, and so there is an easier way to do it in that library.  I will leave this answer here, because it may be interesting in showing how the find type method gets implemented.

Comment: Thanks, for the snippet @SAJ14SAJ, the more perspectives on how to solve a problem, the better ;)

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers so far are using third-party js libraries. The following is an attempt at a straight js solution. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rNfph/

```
var M = [
    {text:'one', coord: [0,0]},
    {text:'two', coord: [1,1]},
    {text:'three', coord: [2,2]},
    {text:'four', coord: [3,3]},
    {text:'five', coord: [4,4]},
    {text:'six', coord: [5,5]},
    {text:'seven', coord: [6,6]},
    {text:'eight', coord: [7,7]},
    {text:'nine', coord: [8,8]},
    {text:'ten', coord: [9,9]}
];

var search = function(str, x, y){

    for(var i=0, len=M.length; i<len; i++){
        if( M[i].text === str && M[i].coord[0] === x && M[i].coord[1] === y ){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}

console.log( search('three', 2, 2) );
console.log( search('three', 1, 2) );
```

Now, take this with a grain of salt. I am not an expert in complexity. There very well could be better ways to do this since this implementation requires iteration through potentially all of the values.

If there was a restriction on this where the value of 'text' is required to be unique, then instead of using an array, you could structure it all as an object (dictionary) and do the checks without needing *any* iterations at all.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mrsh/

```
var M = {
    'one': [0,0],
    'two': [1,1],
    'three': [2,2],
    'four': [3,3]
}

var search = function(key, x, y){

    if( !M[key] || !(M[key][0] === x && M[key][1] === y) ) return false;

    return true;
}

console.log( search('three',2,2) ); //true
console.log( search('three',1,2) ); //false
```

​

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Array.prototype.each) {
   Array.prototype.each = function(callback) {
      var i, l = this.length;
      for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
         if (callback(i, this[i]) === true) return;
      }
   }
}

function anMHasYourMom(m) {
   var found;
   m.each(function(i, el) {
      return found = (
         el.text === "your mom"
         && el.coords[0] === 9
         && el.coords[1] === 9
      );
   });
   return found;
}

var M = [A_1, A_2, ..., A_n];
if (anMHasYourMom(M)) {
   window.alert('It has one!');
}
```